# How to extract a part from a string in R

Tags: regex, string, r

I have a problem when I tried to obtain a numeric part in R. The original strings, for example, is `"buy 1000 shares of Google at 1100 GBP"`

I need to extract the number of the shares (`1000`) and the price (`1100`) separately. Besides, I need to extract the number of the stock, which always appears after `"shares of"`.

I know that `sub` and `gsub` can replace string, but what commands should I use to extract part of a string?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** This extracts all numbers in order:

```
s <- "buy 1000 shares of Google at 1100 GBP"

library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(s, "[0-9.]+", simplify = as.numeric)
```

giving:

```
[1] 1000 1100
```

**2)** If the numbers can be in any order but if the number of shares is always followed by the word "shares" and the price is always followed by GBP then:

```
strapplyc(s, "(\\d+) shares", simplify = as.numeric) # 1000
strapplyc(s, "([0-9.]+) GBP", simplify = as.numeric) # 1100
```

The portion of the string matched by the part of the regular expression within parens is returned.

**3)** If the string is known to be of the form: X shares of Y at Z GBP then X, Y and Z can be extracted like this:

```
strapplyc(s, "(\\d+) shares of (.+) at ([0-9.]+) GBP", simplify = c)
```

*ADDED*  Modified pattern to allow either digits or a dot.  Also added (3) above and the following:

```
strapply(c(s, s), "[0-9.]+", as.numeric)
strapply(c(s, s), "[0-9.]+", as.numeric, simplify = rbind) # if ea has same no of matches

strapply(c(s, s), "(\\d+) shares", as.numeric, simplify = c)
strapply(c(s, s), "([0-9.]+) GBP", as.numeric, simplify = c)

strapplyc(c(s, s), "(\\d+) shares of (.+) at ([0-9.]+) GBP")
strapplyc(c(s, s), "(\\d+) shares of (.+) at ([0-9.]+) GBP", simplify = rbind)
```

Comment: Just tried and it works for "buy 1000 shares of Google at 1100 GBP". However, sometimes it is 1000.00, and sometimes it is 1000, and it seems that by strapplyc it can only get integers instead of floats. And, what if I want to go through a data frame, such as aaa$action?

Comment: Thanks. What about extracting the name of the company? Actually my problem is, first I use some function to extract two substrings, for example, here I've got "1000" and "1100", and then I want to get the strings between them, plus removing "shares of" and "at", leaving only the company's name. I want to do this all at once. Is it possible?

Comment: Have modified the pattern to allow either digits or a dot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sub` function:

```
s <- "buy 1000 shares of Google at 1100 GBP"

# the number of shares
sub(".* (\\d+) shares.*", "\\1", s)
# [1] "1000"

# the stock
sub(".*shares of (\\w+) .*", "\\1", s)
# [1] "Google"

# the price
sub(".* at (\\d+) .*", "\\1", s)
# [1] "1100"
```

---

You can also use `gregexpr` and `regmatches` to extract all substrings at once:

```
regmatches(s, gregexpr("\\d+(?= shares)|(?<=shares of )\\w+|(?<= at )\\d+", 
                       s, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "1000"   "Google" "1100"
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel compelled to include the obligatory `stringr` solution as well.

```
library(stringr)

s <- "buy 1000 shares of Google at 1100 GBP"

str_match(s, "([0-9]+) shares")[2]
[1] "1000"

str_match(s, "([0-9]+) GBP")[2]
[1] "1100"
```

Comment: Try better version of this package - `stringi`. Better, faster and comes with even more handy functions! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract all digits from text use this function from `stringi` package.

"Nd" is the class of decimal digits.

```
    stri_extract_all_charclass(c(123,43,"66ala123","kot"),"\\p{Nd}")
[[1]]
[1] "123"

[[2]]
[1] "43"

[[3]]
[1] "66"  "123"

[[4]]
[1] NA
```

Please note that here 66 and 123 numbers are extracted separatly.